# Time difference of 2 different dates in hh:mm but should in datetime format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, difference

I have two dates @Shutdownfrom and @shutdownto.
I want to get the time difference of these two dates in hh:mm format
 but i also need to add a set of these time differences.
For eg diff1 + diff2... etc in an rdlc report  which is not possible if diff1 is a string in "hh:mm" format.
Is there any way to get time difference in datetime format or is there any way to convert the varchar value got in "hh:mm" format to datetime
I AM DOING IT IN SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 0):

You should store time differences as an integer data type and leave the formatting to your client application.

For example, to calculate the difference between @Shutdownfrom and @Shutdownto you would typically use the `DATEDIFF`-function with an "M" value, to get the difference in integer minutes. You then store this value as an integer, and then you should have no problem adding difference values together (for example 67 minutes + 34 minutes = 101 minutes).

If you must have your database format the integer amount of minutes as "hh:mm", use something like this in a view (assuming your integer column containing the differences is called `Diff`):

```
SELECT CAST(Diff/60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(Diff % 60 AS VARCHAR)) AS [Diff_HHMM]
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan...actually i have got this before ..I have got the  diff in minutes and also converted into hh:mm format which is in varchar. my requirment is that i need the output or result of the difference in time format or someformat which can be converted into timeformat so that  i can add the total duration  in the client application.Actually i am using rdlc reporting where i am not able to add timediff in hh:mm together(since it is varchar)

Comment: SQL Server has no native data type for storing time periods (do not confuse it with the `time` datatype, which is only used to store a specific time of day). You need to store the difference as an integer value, which you pass directly to your application. Then, your application should handle conversion into hh:mm.

Comment: ,thanks again ,but the code for adding those  timediffs in hh:mm format is wat i require